# What is the benefit of the in-memory processing engines with a huge amount of data?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata, batch-processing

Spark performs the best if the dataset fits in memory, in case the dataset doesn't fit, it will use the disk and so it is as fast as hadoop. 
Let's assume that I m dealing with Tera/Peta bytes of data. with a small cluster. Obviously, there is no way to fit it in the memory. 
My observation is, in the big data era most of the dataset are in Giga bytes if not more.

What is then the benefit of the in memory processing engines?

Comment: You already know the benefits of in-memory engines. Gigabytes isn't a lot of memory, though; I have 32G on my desktop, some machines I've used have 128G physical and more. Not all big data needs to operate on petabytes *at a time*, too.

Comment: Spark is not an "in-memory processing engine". This is such a common misconception, partly due to how Spark was promoted in its early days. Spark leverages memory very well, but it does not need to store all the data it processes in memory to be blazing fast. For example, Spark recently [broke the 100 TB sort record](https://databricks.com/blog/2014/10/10/spark-petabyte-sort.html). The sort benchmark it won, known as Daytona Gray, requires that all data be read from disk at the start, sorted, and then written back to disk at the end. There are no "in-memory computation" shortcuts.

Comment: In-memory processing gives the biggest advantages when you are doing iterative computations -- most commonly done with machine learning -- on a dataset. Being able to keep a subset of your massive dataset in memory as you iterate over it is way faster than reading and writing your intermediate results to disk for each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find Spark's advantages over Hadoop's MapReduce are more than just `in-memory computation engine` even input from disk. As far as I can concern, there are at least two major advancements:

1. Spark's `DAG execution engine` over MapReduce's `two phase execution`
2. `Thread level parallel execution` over `Process level parallel execution`

To elaborate a little:

1. For a complex execution plan, Spark's DAGScheduler would slice your plan into stages, at the shuffle edge, but you don't need to add dummy map phase as you do in Hadoop, therefore, eliminate the unnecessary materialization of reduce output into HDFS and read back then as map input.
2. Hadoop's MapReduce has well-known high latency because each task in map reduce is a process, JVM level parallelism is heavy weight when compared with spark's thread level parallelism.